# Right I'm Facing One problem in wordpress edit.php

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

Right now, I'm facing one issue with the WordPress admin site. I want to create a separate show.php without losing WordPress core functionality. Here I want to add our own structure of meta boxes
Anyone is there  to help me out with this problem

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: Are you talking about custom post types? https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-create-custom-post-types-in-wordpress/